# How to disable .save command in Node.js repl?

Tags: node.js

I'm a newbee to Node.js. I was reading `REPL` api just now, I assumed setting environment variable `NODE_REPL_HISTORY` to `""` would turn off `.save` command which produces command lines history file. Was I wrong?

So I decided to set it by `process` module:

```
var repl = require("repl");

process.env['NODE_REPL_HISTORY'] = "";

var replServer = repl.start({
    prompt:"my-app > ",
});

console.log(process.env);

var add = function(a,b){
    return a+b;
};

replServer.context.foo = "bar";

replServer.context.add = add;
```

Unluckily, REPL still produced command lines history file.

Comment: Can you try moving the environment variable setting *before* the `repl.start`?

Comment: Unluckily,it doesn't work

Comment: Too bad :( Well, was worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

`.save` command is [defined](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/47db2472e59772803f020ee8d02b7b17032d72a9/lib/repl.js#L1013) in `lib/repl.js` unconditionally, that is it's present regardless of any environment variables.

```
repl.defineCommand('save', {
  help: 'Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file',
  action: function(file) {
    try {
      fs.writeFileSync(file, this.lines.join('\n') + '\n');
      this.outputStream.write('Session saved to:' + file + '\n');
    } catch (e) {
      this.outputStream.write('Failed to save:' + file + '\n');
    }
    this.displayPrompt();
  }
});
```

You can delete this command by removing it manually from `replServer`:

```
delete replServer.commands.save;
```

Comment: Thanks,I no longer wonder if `.save` is present regard of environment variables.